# How to fix no border under my active list item?

Tags: html, css

I want to put my active list-item go over my border-bottom. Z-index didn't work, I think that that's the case due to the position of the list-items. Do you know how to help me?

Current situation:

```css
.meer_info_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #98ab39;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.meer_info_li{
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(0, 7px);
}

.meer_info_li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active,  .meer_info_li a:hover:not(.active){
  border-right: 1px solid #98ab39;
  border-left: 1px solid #98ab39;
  border-top: 1px solid #98ab39;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meer_info_ul">
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a class="active" href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Perfect Situation:
[image]

Kindregards,
MarioMartin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `overflow: hidden` from the `<ul>` container and add a white border-bottom to your active list element, you can just shift the list element down 1 pixel so it covers the bottom line. Note that I also had to update the `border-radius` to use `border-top-radius` and `border-bottom-radius`. Another improvement is that you should always set the border-width of your list element to 1px to prevents the tabs from changing size. You can set their color to `transparent` to hide them (see: `1px solid transparent`).

```css
.meer_info_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #98ab39;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.meer_info_li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.meer_info_li a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.meer_info_li a.active, .meer_info_li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #98ab39;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meer_info_ul">
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a class="active" href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Added an explanation, glad it worked for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

A way to hack around a similar result.

```css
.meer_info_ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.meer_info_ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #98ab39;
}

.meer_info_li{
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(0, 7px);
}

.meer_info_li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.meer_info_li a.active,  
.meer_info_li a:hover:not(.active){
  border-right: 1px solid #98ab39;
  border-left: 1px solid #98ab39;
  border-top: 1px solid #98ab39;
}
.meer_info_li a.active {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meer_info_ul">
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a class="active" href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

The bootstrap way to manage a similar result.

```css
.meer_info_ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #98ab39;
}

.meer_info_li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.meer_info_li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.meer_info_li a.active,  
.meer_info_li a:hover:not(.active){
  border-color: #98ab39 #98ab39 #fff;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meer_info_ul">
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a class="active" href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="meer_info_li"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps.